# how do i identify which operating system is on which partition and how do i delete old operating system

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning

my computer recently crashed and the error code 0xc0000225 appeared.So I looked online for ways to solve the issue.after trying multiple different possible fixes that didn't work I tried reinstalling windows.First I followed the instructions on how to installed the Media Creation Tool on a usb drive

Then I tried the installation process where i get to keep personal files like videos and music, but it said that i couldn't while trying to install from the usb drive. So i used custom settings and it said to select a partition.Honestly I no nothing about computers so when it came to choosing which partition to reinstall windows on i just choose whichever worked(by the way i only have one harddrive).

after that my computer restarted and it said to choose which os to start, without choosing one it seemed to just pick one. Windows 10 setup started with cortana and after that I found my computer worked and there was a file called windows.old with all my old files on it.

Now that my computer seems to be working again I want to delete the corrupt/broken/old windows 10 os, but don't know where to find it or which partition its on. Is it even possible for me to that? and if so? how?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have used for the installation the partition where Windows was
already installed.

The installation created a new `C:\Windows` folder, and renamed the old one to
`C:\Windows.old`.

You may delete `C:\Windows.old` if everything works all right.
However, after 28 days Windows will in any case delete most of it, leaving only your
personal stuff. I would suggest leaving the folder alone until you will need the space.